# Multiple forms overwriting eachothers variables

Tags: c++-cli, multiple-forms

I am making multiple windows forms in C++/CLI to run tests simultaneously, i can do this but i have variables defined inside my class as private but when the second form writes to its version of the variable it overwrites it for all the other forms version of this variable.

```
array<String^>^args = Environment::GetCommandLineArgs();
             int args1 = System::Convert::ToInt16(args[1]);
             int i;
             #pragma omp parallel for 
              for(i = 0; i < args1; i++)
              {
                Sleep(1000);
                Form1^ form1 = gcnew Form1(i);
                form1->Show();
              }



private ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
private:
static int formnumber;
static SerialPort^ serialPort = gcnew SerialPort();
public:
    Form1(int formnum)
    {
        array<String^>^args = Environment::GetCommandLineArgs();
        formnumber = formnum;
        int a = 65;
        jigid = a + formnum;
        comnumber = formnumber + Convert::ToInt16(args[2]);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

when i create 2 forms formnum will always be 1 for later use in the forms beacuse the creation of the 2nd form overwrote formnum in the 1st form.
how do i make it so that the forms cant overwrite each others variables?

Comment: That's certainly not C++. I fixed it for you. But in the future, please be aware that C++/CLI is a *very* different beast than C++

Comment: There are two options here, 1. you either copied this code (or parts of it) from somewhere else without completely understanding it, in this case you should first consult some serious learning resource on C++/CLI and try to understand each line of your code before trying to *SO-solve* particular problems with it. Or 2. you consciously wrote this code yourself, including the `static` in your variable declarations, in which case you must have had some reason to declare them `static` and the question is just obsolete.

Comment: i was originally declaring the variables outside the class and there was a compile time error that was solved by declaring the variables as static so when i moved the variables inside the class i kept the static included and didnt even think about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't declare them static!........................

Comment: Thanks works perfectly now. Had to change: static SerialPort^ serialPort = gcnew SerialPort(); to: SerialPort^ serialPort; and inside the form: serialPort = gcnew SerialPort(); because it complained about initialising it.